# display loadingscreen while async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this async task that call an web service and parse an xml

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
super.onPreExecute();
time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
 protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
  //code 
 }

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
    difftime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
 }
```

while async task is executing I want to display an loading screen,but the loading screen finishes before async task finish if I am doing like this

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);

            final CallWebService callTarif = new CallWebService(6,sett.getDeviceId());
            callTarif.execute();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
        @Override 
            public void run() { 

                LoadingScreen.this.finish(); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, NextActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);            
            } 

        }
        },callTarif.difftime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `postDelayed` is called before completing the **AsyncTask**.

Just put these code lines

```
LoadingScreen.this.finish(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

in `opPostExecute()` of AsyncTask.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);

    difftime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    LoadingScreen.this.finish(); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);      
}
```

And remove **Handler** `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){`

Answer (score 0):

start your loading screen onPreExecute method and kill it onPostExecute method of the async task

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Handler for showing loading when accessing webservice using async task . use `onPreExecute()` method of AsyncTask to Show loading Screen and finish it inside `onPostExecute` because this method called when `doInBackground` execution complete . change code code as :

```
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
            // show loading bar here
      }
@Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                 // do network operation here
            return null;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {      
          // dismiss loading bar here         
      }
```

Comment: i have to show an loading screen with a slide show,not a loading bar